# Import value from an input to another function

Tags: python

```
def userinput():
    amount_purchased = input('Enter the amount of bags to be purchased: ')

#The amount entered is compared and the rate of discount is printed
def find_discount(amount_purchased):
    amount_purchased = userinput()
    if amount_purchased <=25:
        discount_rate=0.0
        print('The discount rate is 0%')
    elif amount_purchased <=50:
        discount_rate=0.05
        print('The discount rate is 5%')
    elif amount_purchased <=99:
        discount_rate=0.1
        print('The discount rate is 10%')
        print('The discount rate is 10%')
```

Hi, I'm having trouble trying to get the value from 'userinput' to show up in
the function find discount. I can get it to work if I make userinput a global variable,
but I would like to have it inside a function so that I can change the order it appears
in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value from the function:

```
def userinput():
    amount_purchased = input('Enter the amount of bags to be purchased: ')
    return amount_purchased
```

It's also possible to return the result of `input()` directly:

```
def userinput():
    return input('Enter the amount of bags to be purchased: ')
```

Also: why does `find_discount` receive `amount_purchased` as parameter? It seems to me that `amount_purchased` would get its value from whatever `userinput` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value from `userinput` and probably converting to `int`

```
def userinput():
    return int(input('Enter the amount of bags to be purchased: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value from the userinput function
So change your function to this :

```
def userinput():
        amount_purchased = input("Enter the amount of bags to be purchased: ")
        return amount_purchased
```

Good luck